# How do I use Twitter API v2 to retrieve Tweets longer than 280 characters?

Tags: twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python, twitter-api-v2

Twitter recently allowed verified users to Tweet more than 280 characters, up to 4000. When I use the API to retrieve one of these longer Tweets I don't receive the full text - it's cut off around 280 characters. I don't see any notes about this in the Twitter API documentation, maybe I missed it. Are there any additional fields/expansions I need to request when retrieving a Tweet? Here are the fields and expansions I'm currently using (in Python):

```
tweet_fields_list = ["id",
                     "text",
                     "author_id",
                     "created_at",
                     "conversation_id",
                     "in_reply_to_user_id",
                     "referenced_tweets",
                     "attachments",
                     "entities"]

expansions_list = ["referenced_tweets.id", "attachments.media_keys"]

media_fields_list = ["media_key","type","url"]
```

Comment: I guess it also only [Blue subscribers](https://help.twitter.com/en/using-twitter/twitter-blue-how-to#create-longer-tweet)

Comment: any update on this? same issue here...

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible right now. It was also discussed on the official Twitter Developer forums: https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-to-fetch-longer-tweet/186089

Comment: have you found how to fetch more than 280 chars?

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `tweet.fields=note_tweet` to the query to get "Information about Tweets with more than 280 characters." per the [docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/api-reference/get-tweets-search-recent).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it is not possible currently. It appears that they are **still applying** 280 characters limit whether you are **Twitter Blue** subs or not.

If you exceed the **280 character limit**, the api returns a **400 bad request** error.

Take a look: https://twitter.com/daily_reviewss/status/1690131882153758720

[image]